# Found out if OLEObject is ComboBox

Tags: vba, combobox

Is it possible to find out with a For Each loop to find out if an OLEObject is a ComboBox?
I Have a couple of Comboboxes on a worksheet but also CommandButtons and what else.

```
Dim comboB As OLEObject
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet

For Each comboB in ws.OLEObjects
If typeName(comboB) = "ComboBox" Then
'Do something
End if
Next
```

The problem is that a TypeName(stringvalue) only works on controls.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code :

```
Sub sample()

   Dim comboB As Variant
   Dim ws As Worksheet
   Set ws = ActiveSheet

    With ws
        For Each comboB In .OLEObjects
            If TypeName(comboB.Object) = "ComboBox" Then
               MsgBox TypeName(comboB) & " is a combo box"
            End If
        Next

    End With
End Sub
```